# Nested loop in Python Pandas - combining subloop results into concatenated df saved with group name in file name

Tags: python, pandas, loops, nested

I have a df that looks like the sample below. I'm trying to to run a loop by group that:

- does a separate API query for each id2 in the group, holds these in
  memory
- the API result is a df (or I coerce into a df) [edit]
- concatenates all the id2 results into a new dataframe
- saves the new concatenated dataframe as a new .csv with id1 in the
  filename.

For the example to get the loop set up correctly, a suitable alternative to actually querying the API would be to just print some text & DESC as a new row in a new .csv.

I've sketched what I think the loops would look like in a mix of Python and plain language (in CAPS with * *).

I'm usually an R user, but need to use Python for the API query. How do I translate the sketch or outline below into working Python?

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1,1,'ab'],[1,2,'bc'],[1,3,'de'],[2,1,'gh'],[2,2,'hi'],[2,3,'jk'],[3,1,'kl'],[3,2,'lm']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['id1','id2','DESCR'])
df_gp = df.groupby(id1)
```

- id1 is a grouping variable (about 34K unique values)
- id2 identifies obs within the group (each id1 has 1-20 unique id2s, it is a numeric indicator of the position of the obs in within id1, an id variable)
- DESCR is unique to id2 and used to query an API to get information about id2

```
for name, group in df_gp: 
    for i in range(1, len(*WHAT_HERE_ID2?*)): 
        result[i] = *PRINT(DESCR) OR SOMETHING JUST TO CREATE A SAMPLE OBJECT_to be replaced w/API code*
        result[i] = pd.DataFrame(result[i])
    filename = 'myfileprefix_' + df_gp.loc[name] + '.csv'
    all = *how to CONCATENATE result[i] through result[max(id2)] into one df*    
    all.to_csv(filename)
```

Note: The whole reason that I'm needing to do each id2 API query separately is b/c if I submit all the id2s as a group in one query for id1, it sometimes exceeds the query limit (e.g., if multiple id2s return large # of records, it exceeds query limit, but when I do one id2 at a time, this never happens).

The result should be 3 .csv files named:

- myfileprefix_1.csv
- myfileprefix_2.csv
- myfileprefix_3.csv

with the results for all the id2 queries inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over rows with `iterrows` inside the grouped DataFrame:

```
# a function to be replaced with actual API call
def mock_api_call(v):
    return f'api output for {v}'

# iterate over groups by `id1`
for id1, g in df_gp:

    # iterate over rows inside each group
    for i, r in g.iterrows():
        g.loc[i, 'result'] = mock_api_call(r['DESCR'])

    fn = f'myfileprefix{id1}.csv'
    g.to_csv(fn)
```

The output in `myfileprefix1.csv`, for example, will be:

```
   id1  id2 DESCR             result
0    1    1    ab  api output for ab
1    1    2    bc  api output for bc
2    1    3    de  api output for de
```

---

P.S. As a slightly less verbose option, you can also use `apply` instead of `iterrows`:

```
for id1, g in df_gp:
    g['result'] = g['DESCR'].apply(mock_api_call)
    fn = f'myfileprefix{id1}.csv'
    g.to_csv(fn)
```

**Update:** Based on your clarification that an API call returns a DataFrame:

```
for id1, g in df_gp:
    # set up DataFrame to collect all API responses for the group
    dfg = pd.DataFrame()
    
    # iterate over rows inside each group
    for i, r in g.iterrows():
        # get DataFrame from API call
        dfi = mock_api_call(r['DESCR'])
        
        # if needed, add columns to API response DataFrame, e.g.
        # dfi['DESCR'] = r['DESCR']
        # ...
        
        # concatenate new results to dfg
        dfg = pd.concat([dfg, dfi], ignore_index=True)

    fn = f'myfileprefix{id1}.csv'
    dfg.to_csv(fn)
```

Comment: @MichelleD. Please see the update in my answer. This will loop through the groups, concatenating all API responses within a group into one DataFrame (`dfg`) and saving it to a CSV file (one per group)

Comment: Thank YOU @perl! ARGH. I edited without seeing your response b/c I didn't refresh. Will try this variation.